# Typescript Mixin Dynamic Interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface Base {
}

interface A {
    a: number
}

interface B {
    b: number;
}

interface C {
    c: number
}

interface AB extends A, B, Base {}
interface AC extends A, C, Base {}
interface BC extends B, C, Base {}
interface ABC extends A, B, C, Base {}
```

`Base` Can extends any interface as selective.
I want to know make Extended interface as other syntax.
because the number of extendable class can be increased.

```
interface Mix2<T, U> extends T, U, Base {
}
type AB = Mix2<A, B>
type BC = Mix2<B, C>
```

I know, it's wrong syntax, just example as my expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a type that represents an object that has to have members of two other defined types you can use an intersection type

```
type AB = A & B & Base
type BC = B & C & Baee
```

You can read more about intersection types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: working as I expect. just my stupid IDE are not work like VSC.